# Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message could not be sent.
>
> Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

I can't seem to find a way to make PHPMailer work under CentOS. Mail work just fine under Windows with XAMPP but I always get this error under Linux.

The SMTP server is a Lotus Domino listening on port 25, CentOS machine has NO firewall at all and the strange thing is that even mail() does not work. It returns nothing (while on Windows returns 1). If I send an email through telnet via CentOS server it works just fine so I don't think it is a network problem. It must be related to PHP but I don't know how.

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "192.168.x.x";
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->From = "xxx@xxx.it";
$mail->FromName = "XXX";
$mail->AddAddress("xxx@xxx.it");
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body    = "Test";
if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Just to clarify the code above works on XAMPP (Windows).

I debugged the error on PHPMailer and error happens here (class.smtp.php method Connect()):

```
$this->smtp_conn = @fsockopen($host,    // the host of the server
                             $port,    // the port to use
                             $errno,   // error number if any
                             $errstr,  // error message if any
                             $tval);   // give up after ? secs
// verify we connected properly
if(empty($this->smtp_conn)) {
  $this->error = array("error" => "Failed to connect to server",
                       "errno" => $errno,
                       "errstr" => $errstr);
  if($this->do_debug >= 1) {
    echo "SMTP -> ERROR: " . $this->error["error"] . ": $errstr ($errno)" . $this->CRLF . '<br />';
  }
  return false;
}
```

It looks like it can't open the Socket...

**UPDATE:** Using $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; as suggested by Alvaro produced this output:

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13)

Comment: Have you tried specifying login credentials?

Comment: There are none. What do you mean by the way? You mean set them as ""?

Comment: FYI tryed 

`$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "";
$mail->Password = "";`

just now, no luck.

Comment: Can you paste SMTP info from your php.ini file or phpinfo() ?

Comment: The only two SMTP related variables that I can see with phpinfo() are SMTP (localhost) and smtp_port (25). They have the exact value on Windows as well. I tryed changing SMTP according to my actual IP but it changed nothing. Do I have to restart Apache when I change these values?

Comment: What happens if you try `telnet 192.168.x.x 25`?

Comment: It works, already said that, I can send emails through telnet via CentOS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can enable debug mode with the `SMTPDebug` property, e.g.:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// 1 = errors and messages
// 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
```

Error messages will be echoed to screen.

**Update:**

A *permission denied* error message using [fsockopen()](http://php.net/fsockopen) suggests that the user PHP runs as is not allowed to open a socket. If you'd double-checked that there's no firewall, it's possible that's a [SELinux problem](http://yml.com/fv-b-1-619/selinux--apache-httpd--php-establishing-socket-connections-using-fsockopen---et-al.html) :-?

Comment: Nice catch here, now it gives this error `SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13)`. Can it be related to Linux user's permissions?

Comment: You are a genius, I used the command that I found on your link and it worked. So IT WAS a network related problem after all. Well now I know what to do if I get the same error in the future! Thank you all guys, appreciate the help ;)

Answer (score 43):

OS CentOS 6.3

Couldn’t send emails

after some reserch turned out that SELinux is blocking the communication

SELinux is activated and configured by default. As such  SELinux does not allow Apache (httpd,phpmailer) to use the sendmail function and make any sort of network connection.

Using the getsebool command we can check if httpd demon is allowed to make a connection over the network and send an email.

```
getsebool httpd_can_sendmail
getsebool httpd_can_network_connect
```

This command will return a boolean on or off. If its off, we can set it on using the following:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Now you can test your php, code to see if SendMail work properly or not.

Comment: You are my hero today.

Comment: You sir saved me. I also want to point out that the setsebool commands can run a little slow on some versions of CENTOS so just be patient when running the commands.

Comment: You saved my day, and confirmed to go through to understand SELinux well. Thank you.

Comment: This solution made my day. I was trying to figure out for the whole weak with no clue. Thanks!

Comment: I think `httpd_can_sendmail` is not needed if you're using an external SMTP server. This setting is for using the `sendmail` program, i.e. if you have a mail server running on the same box. Setting `httpd_can_network_connect` is sufficient. It is better (more secure) to enable only one setting, whichever is needed. Also, however, it might not be the most secure option because it allows httpd to initiate _any_ outgoing connection to _any_ box. So this solution is better than disabling SELinux, but is not the most secure solution.