# PHP mailer not sending email on server

Tags: php, forms, email, phpmailer

My PHPMailer `script` works fine on `xampp` local server.But on my website that is located on a apache server isn't working.I think in my apache server doesn't finds the right location of `phpMailerAutoload.php` but I'm not sure.
I'll be very thankfull if someone can help me with this .

EDIT:When I press the "send" button it displays the error that i set up to display in my PhpMailer `script`.(the last `else`)

My PHPMailer `script`:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once 'phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$errors= [];

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])){
    $fields=[
        'name'=>$_POST['name'],
        'email'=>$_POST['email'],
        'message'=>$_POST['message']
        ];

foreach($fields as $field => $data){
    if(empty($data)){ 
        $errors[]='Il <b>' . $field . '</b> è necessario.';
    }
}


if(isset($_POST['tel'])){
    $sec_fields=[
    'tel'=>$_POST['tel']
    ];
}

/*------Validation--------*/

if(!empty($_REQUEST['name'])){
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/",$name)){
        $errors[]='Il <b>nome</b> non è valido.';
    }
}

if(!empty($_REQUEST['email'])){
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $valid = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if($valid == false){
        $errors[]='L\'indirizzo <b>email</b> non è valido.';
    }
}

/*------Creating PHPMailer Class-------*/

    if(empty($errors)) {
        $m= new PHPMailer;

        $m -> isSMTP();
        $m -> SMTPAuth = true;

        $m->Host = 'wolf.dnshigh.com';
        $m->Username = 'email@danadesign.it';
        $m->Password = 'password';
        $m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $m->Port = 465;

        $m->isHTML();

        $m->Subject = 'Avete ricevuto un nuovo messaggio .' ;
        $m->Body =' Inviato da : ' . $fields['name'] .  ' (' .$fields['email'] . ') <br><br> <p>' . $fields['message'] . '<br><br> </p> <p>Telefono: ' . $sec_fields['tel'] . '</p>' ;  

        $m->FromName = 'DanaDesign Mail';

        $m->AddAddress ('MyinboxEmail@yahoo.it', 'My name');

        /*-----Sending Email------*/

        if ($m->send()) {
            header('Location: redirect.html');
            die();
        } else {
            $errors[]='Siamo spiacenti,non siamo riusciti a inviare il messaggio.Si prega di riprovare più tardi.';
        }

    }

} else {
    $errors[]='Qualcosa è andato storto.';
}
header('Location: contact.php');
$_SESSION['errors']= $errors;
$_SESSION['fields']= $fields;
$_SESSION['sec_fields']= $sec_fields;


?>
```

And my contact form:

```
<section>
            <h2>Write us a message</h2>
            <div class="contact">
                <?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>
                <div class="panel">
                    <ul><li> <?php echo implode('</li><li> ',$errors); ?> </li></ul>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <form method="post" action="contact-script.php">
                    <label>
                        <img src="img/person.png" alt="Person Icon"> Nome*                  
                       <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" <?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? 'value="' . e($fields['name']) . '"' : ''     ?> />
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <img src="img/telephone.png" alt="Telephone Icon"> Telefono                       
                       <input type="text" name="tel" autocomplete="off" <?php echo isset($sec_fields['tel']) ? 'value="' . e($sec_fields['tel']) . '"' : ''     ?> />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <img src="img/mail.png" alt="Mail Icon">Indirizzo email*                      
                       <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" <?php echo isset($fields['email']) ? 'value="' . e($fields['email']) . '"' : ''     ?> /> 
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <img src="img/message.png" alt="Message Icon">Messaggio*                      
                       <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="2"> <?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message'])  : ''  ?> </textarea>
                    </label>

                    <input type="submit" value="Invia" />                        
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Some text is in Italian language , I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Look at the error log on the live server.

Comment: (XAMPP *is* Apache). And whenever something doesn't work … enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. And there's also `->SMTPDebug` for PHPMailer.

Comment: *"Some text is in Italian language"* - no problema.

Comment: I don't see anything changing if I enable that

Comment: a) Search for the zillion duplicates of this question. b) `$m->SMTPDebug = 2;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not connect to SMTP host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489037/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host)

Comment: have you searched in the error log?

Comment: Yes and It doesn't say anything ..