# Connection could not be established with host mail trap.io [permission denied #13]

Tags: laravel, email, permissions, swiftmailer

I am trying to connect to mailtrap.io from CentOS server to send emails. The following error occurs:

"Connection could not be established with host mail trap.io [permission denied #13]"

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Could be anything, including wrong or not provided api-key/user-pass.

Comment: @HamidAlaei I have included the username and password, as well as the port provided by mailtrap.io

Comment: That is because SELinux blocks sending mails. I had same issue  found solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18399929/1933690

Answer (score 9):

This could be due to SELinux blocking the connection.

I had the same issue and this solved it:

First check to see if httpd can send mail (if it is on or off)

```
$> getsebool httpd_can_sendmail
$> getsebool httpd_can_network_connect
```

If the response is: OFF then you could turn it ON as follow:

```
$> sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
$> sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

My source for this solution was [Could not connect to SMTP host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489037/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host/18399929#18399929)

Comment: Work like charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CentOs then run this `commands`

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail true
```

and then

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect true
```