# Hostbuddy SMTP mail test, having troubles, could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, html, email, post, smtp

I am very new to php and im trying to set up a postmaster, I am using Hostbuddy for my hosting site and downloaded their smtp information for my server.

I got these files from them automatically uploaded to my server for testing the smtp:

```
class.phpmailer.php
class.smtp.php
index.php
web.config
```

I think i am entering the correct information for the test. but i keep getting a callback that says, "Could not connect to smtp server".

Here is the index.php so you guys can see what is going on.

```
<Center><h2>PHP Test Email Script</h2></center>
<?php
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" target="_blank">
<Table align = center>

  <tr><td>From Email: <td><input type="text" name="uname"> i.e yourname@yourdomain.com</tr>
  <tr><td>Email Password: <td><input type="password" name="pass"></tr>
<tr><td>Host: <td><input type="text" name="host"> i.e Mail.YourDomain.com</tr>
 <tr><td>To:<td> <input type="text" name="to"></tr>

  <tr><td colspan =2 align = center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email"></tr>
</table>
  </form>

  <?php 
} 
else {    // the user has submitted the form

include("class.phpmailer.php"); //you have to upload class files "class.phpmailer.php" and "class.smtp.php"

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Host = $_POST["host"];

$mail->Username = $_POST["uname"];
$mail->Password = $_POST["pass"]; 

$mail->From = $_POST["uname"];
$mail->FromName = "demouser";

$mail->AddAddress($_POST["to"],"test");
$mail->Subject = "This is the subject";
$mail->Body = "This is a sample message using SMTP authentication";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$str1= "gmail.com";
$str2=strtolower($_POST["uname"]);
If(strstr($str2,$str1))
{
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
echo "<br><br> * Please double check the user name and password to confirm that both of them are correct. <br><br>";
echo "* If you are the first time to use gmail smtp to send email, please refer to this link :http://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1546/send-email-from-gmail-with-smtp-authentication-but-got-5_5_1-authentication-required-error.aspx?KBSearchID=137388";
} 
else {
echo "Message has been sent";
}
}
else{
    $mail->Port = 25;
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
echo "<br><BR>* Please double check the user name and password to confirm that both of them are correct. <br>";
} 
else {
echo "Message has been sent";
}
}  
}
?>
```

Any info would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: this answer could help (or maybe a dupe?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489037/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the true smtp gmail so you can add :

```
smtp-relay.gmail.com    smtp.gmail.com  aspmx.l.google.com
```

Setting requirement

```
Options : port 25, 465 ou 587
Protocoles SSL/TLS (Secure Socket Layer/Transport Layer Security)

Port 465 (SSL require).
Port 587 (TLS require).
Adresses dynamic IP allowed. 

Port 25.
TLS no require.
Adresses dynamic IP allowed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i had it set up correctly, it just took a few hours for hostbuddy to get the smtp server set up. Works great now :) thanks for the suggestions!