# How to resolve SMTP could not connect error? [post STARTTLS problem]

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, starttls

I have installed php mailer using composer composer require phpmailer/phpmailer. I followed instructions from this website https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-send-an-email-using-phpmailer.

Below is my code for sending email.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
try 
{ 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->isSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host       = 'mail.example.in'; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;      
    $mail->Username   = 'username'; 
    $mail->Password   = 'password';       
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';   
    $mail->Port       = 587;   
    $mail->setFrom('owner@gmail.com', 'Owner'); 
    $mail->addAddress('receipent@gmail.com'); 
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = "Hello this is subject";
    $mail->Body    = "Hello this is message;
    $mail->send();

    echo "Mail has been sent successfully!"; 
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{ 
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}"; 
}
```

When I comment `$mail->isSMTP();` and send mail, I get the result as message sent but I dont get it in my Gmail inbox.

when I uncomment `$mail->isSMTP();` I get error message as shown in below image.

[image: smtp error]

My project is hosted in godaddy server.
Even if I use php mail() function to send mail, response is mail send successfully, but it does not get delivered into my Gmail inbox

Comment: Looks like your problem is related to [This](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1781). The error message is certanly the same, and the reasons are probably also the same.

Comment: Read what [the troubleshooting guide says about GoDaddy](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#godaddy), and also what it says about seeing an [SMTP QUIT immediately after STARTTLS](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not connect to SMTP host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489037/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Gmail, you should follow the steps here to manually add Google MX records to your GoDaddy account: 
https://uk.godaddy.com/help/point-my-domains-email-service-to-google-7936

Unfortunately it takes some days for changes to be reflected.

Then you need to disable security features, change your php mailer config like:

```
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; 
$mail->Port = 25;
```

Hope this solves.

**------EDIT------**

Later I figured out that the emails go to spam folder when the port is 25. I changed the connection to TLS and now I receive them as normal.

Here is the code from my website, it works on Godaddy, I receive e-mails to my gmail account.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'true';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Username = "********@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "**********";
$mail->SetFrom("********@gmail.com");
$mail->AddAddress("********@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = " your subject";
$mail->Body = "your body";
```

Comment: is there any way to avoid emails going into inbox instead of spam folder

Comment: Notice that I don't have     $mail->isSMTP();   in my code. It only worked after I removed that line for some reason.

Comment: it worked for me too after removing  $mail->isSMTP();