# How to fix "Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed"?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I’m stuck at an error sending mail to the user. I am using Centos 7, and running php web using phpmailer to proceed with sending mail as below structure. It works perfectly fine when running on xampp localhost, but when I run on Centos I get

> Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed

I tried everything but still can’t fix it, I tried commenting the line `$mail->isSMTP(true);` it works, but no email is sent to the client. I also tried checking port 587, 25, and 465 to see if it listens via telnet : `telnet stmp.gmail.com 587(25,465)` and the result is 220. I also installed phpmailer on centos, but not sure why it won’t connect to stmp server.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->isSMTP(true);
            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = "my_email@gmail.com";
            $mail->Password = "my_password";
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->From = "my_email@gmail.com";
            $mail->FromName = "No Reply";
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = $body;
            $mail->AddAddress($email_to);

            if (!$mail->send()) {
            $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
                echo 'send_mail_failed';
                print_r($error);


            } else {
                $update_password_byEmail = "UPDATE account SET password=:gen_password WHERE name=:currentUser AND email=:currentEmail;";
                $stmt_gen_pass_update = $sqlWeb->prepare($update_password_byEmail);
                $stmt_gen_pass_update->bindValue(':gen_password', md5($password_generate));
                $stmt_gen_pass_update->bindValue(':currentUser', $usernameOfEmail);
                $stmt_gen_pass_update->bindValue(':currentEmail', $target_email);
                $stmt_gen_pass_update->execute();
                $stmt_gen_pass_update->closeCursor();

                echo 'send_mail_successful';
            }
        } else {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
            echo 'send_mail_error';
            //echo $error;
        }
```

Comment: Try setting the debug level & see what that gets you.

Comment: You have an extra `else` with no `if`.

Comment: There may be a firewall blocking the connection to smtp.gmail.com.

Comment: Don't focus on If condition, the main thing I want to figure out that the mail cannot send, and could not reach the stmp server. I have no firewall on the centos, Also SElinux was disabled.

Comment: Always [search before you post](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer+SMTP+connect%28%29+failed). This question has been answered literally hundreds of times before, and it will be far faster for you than waiting for answers to this question. Next, read [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) which *also* tells you how to diagnose and possibly solve this exact problem.

Comment: You've clearly tried some things, but have not shown any output in your question, so we can't diagnose anything. For example you say you get a `220` response with telnet, but neglect to show the actual output, so we can't spot things like upstream redirection. Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3` and add the output to your question, and then we might be able to get somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not connect to SMTP host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489037/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host)